# Want to create Regex for nested to escape nested parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to compare string with parentheses as ex.

```
String: @required (
              abc ( xyz:54554 )
)
```

Then If I want to confirm that `@required ()` should be there then above one should return true or we can say match.

Current regex only works and return "`abc ( xyz:54554 )`" instead of whole.

Tried: `\([^()]*\)`

Comment: Java OR Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want using start and end tokens.  I recommend you `trim()` your input first.

```
/^@required\s*\((.*)\)$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/JPyDhj/1